# How to multiply the complex elements by float numbers in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

```
import numpy as np
beta= 0.9
A=[1+1j,2+2j]   
real=np.zeros((1,2))
for i in range(1):
   for l in range(2):
       real[i,j] = real[i,j]-beta*A[i,j]
```

I am not familiar with the computation of different types of arrays in `numpy`. How can I make the code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your original code is that the result of

```
real[i, j] - beta * A[i, j]
```

will be complex, but you created `real` using `np.zeros`, which will give you a float64 array unless you explicitly specify a different dtype. Since there is no safe way to cast a complex value to a float, the assignment to `real[i, j]` will raise a `TypeError`.

One way to solve the problem would be to initialize `real` with a complex dtype:

```
real = np.zeros((1, 2), dtype=np.complex)
```

If you make `A` a numpy array, you can use broadcasting to do the multiplication in one go without pre-allocating `real` and without looping:

```
import numpy as np

beta = 0.9
A = np.array([1 + 1j, 2 + 2j])
real = -beta * A

print(repr(real))
# array([-0.9-0.9j, -1.8-1.8j])
```

It looks like you'd probably benefit from reading some of the examples [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Comment: @RayHsu: If this answers your question (which it looks to me like it does), please accept it.